# Start animation after intro page is open jQuery advanced animation

Tags: jquery, animation

I have an intro page with jQuery animation. It slides top and bottom sides of the page to open a website. In addition, I have an advanced animation inside the website itself which starts with scaling and rotating **WELCOME** image. I want WELCOME image to start scaling and rotating after intro page is done but not simultaneously.How can I possibly do it?  I tried to use `.stop(true, true).delay(7000)` and no success. I would highly appreciate any feedback and help. Here is what I did so far

`<div id="welcome"><img src="images/welcome___.png" width="30%"></div>`

```
#welcome {
position: absolute;
top: 8%;
left: 8%;
}


$(document).ready(function(){
    var logo = $('#welcome');
    var scaleVar = 0;
    var rotateVar = 0;

    $({scaleVar: 0, rotateVar: 0}).animate(
    {
        scaleVar: 3,
        rotateVar: 360
    },
    {
        duration: 6000,
        step: function(now, ab){

            if(ab.prop == 'scaleVar')
                scaleVar = now;
            else if(ab.prop == 'rotateVar')
                rotateVar = now;
            logo.stop(true, true).delay(7000).fadeIn(4000);
            logo.css('transform', 'scale(' + scaleVar + ') rotate(' + rotateVar + 'deg)')
            logo.animate({left: '28%'}, 4000, 'easeOutBounce'); 
            logo.fadeOut(7000);
        }
      }
    )
});
```

Intro page opens the website within 3 seconds

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/animate/ - Note that `animate` takes a `complete` argument which is a function that fires once the animation is finished. There is an example on that page.

Answer (score 0):

To chain animations, you can use the `complete` parameter of [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

> **Complete Function**
>
> If supplied, the complete callback function is fired once the
>   animation is complete. This can be useful for stringing different
>   animations together in sequence. The callback is not sent any
>   arguments, but this is set to the DOM element being animated. If
>   multiple elements are animated, the callback is executed once per
>   matched element, not once for the animation as a whole.

This works fine for a short chain of sequential animations, but if you need to wait on concurrent animations to complete (which it sounds like you are) or have a long list of animations to run through, you can use the [deferred object API](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)  (specifically, `.promise()` and `$.when()`) to properly chain your sequence of events. In your case, it allows you to wait until all of the intro animations are done, before starting your logo animation.

```
function animateIntro() {
  var introElements = $('<selector for all elements animated in intro>');

  // do the intro animation on introElements

  return introElements.promise();
}

function animateWelcomeLogo() {
  $('#logo').animate(...);
}

$.when(animateIntro()).done(animateWelcomeLogo);
```

or,

```
$.when(
  $('#top').animate(...),
  $('#bottom').animate(...),
).done(function() {
  $('#logo').animate(...);
});
```